# multiple commands in if statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How would I have more than one thing happen when a condition is true?

```
if(none == '' ){
  alert("Thank you, " + fname + " " + lname);
  window.location = "switcher.html";
  more stuff;
}
```

Oh, sorry I should've been more clear, anything after the alert doesn't happen. I didn't specify this but even if the `window.location` is moved to the bottom, it doesn't work.

Comment: excuse me ? Please elaborate more.

Comment: What is the question? To make multiple statements execute when an `if` condition, you just put multiple statements inside the braces like you are already doing.  What is your question beyond what you are already showing?  FYI, you can't execute more code after setting `window.location` because the page will change and this page's javascript will stop executing.

Comment: Move the `window.location` line as the last one. Once you've left the page the script execution halts.

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here isn't that multiple things aren't happening. It's that you're changing location after your alert, which kills the rest of the execution, so you never get to "more stuff" cause you've moved on to a different page. Move window.location to either be the last thing in your method, or call it from a different method. There's a good chance that the "more stuff" you have is going to be useless if you just up and shift pages (though of course, I have no idea what "more stuff" is so maybe it's entirely valid to do it and then go elsewhere).

Comment: Should've been more clear, nothing after the alert works. I was asking if there was another way more than one thing can happen under one condition.

Comment: no. all your statements will be executed one after the other. Your alert is not halting execution (as per this example: http://jsfiddle.net/bzYMC/ ), so if your "other stuff" isn't working it's for some other reason.  You may want to post your 'more stuff' in because there's a good chance the problem is in that stuff.

Comment: I've eliminated the "more stuff" but it still won't work. It still alerts, but does not relocate to another page.

Comment: 2 things to test
1) is `switcher.html` (case sensitive) sitting in the same directory as the file that's calling this script?

2) try: `self.location.href="switcher.html";`

Comment: It still won't work, I added another alert after the `self.location.href` and it skips over the `self.location.href` and shows me the second alert

Comment: ok, well... clearly you original question has been answered, so, please click the checkmark. As to why your self.location.href isn't working... that is indeed quite odd, but I promise that you're doing something wrong, though I have no clue what that is.